# csv-table formatting in Python docstrings (Sphinx) - multiple lines in one cell

Tags: python, csv, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring

I'm using Sphinx to document a Python project.

There seems to be a bit of inconsistency with the `.. csv-table::` directive.

The main issue is a new line in a cell. And my questionable mental health.

The following code:

```
.. csv-table::
    :header: Header1, Header2, Header3

    A, B, "These lines appear as one line, 
    even though they are written in two lines."
    C, D, "| These lines appear as two lines, 
    | but they are indented, and my OCD will simply not allow it."
    E, F, "| If I continue this line in another line,
    it will appear in a new line."
    G, H, "If there is a blank line between the two lines,

    there will be a blank line between the lines."
```

Will render as:

[image]

I have searched through the entire reStructuredText manual, but could not find a way to solve it.

Is there any way to write two lines in one cell that will appear as the 2nd row, but without the indentation?

The theme is sphinx_rtd_theme.

I found the theme.css file (C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sphinx_rtd_theme\static\css\theme.css), but I can't find the section of the table definition for newline styling

Comment: Why do you have a `|` in there? Simply remove it.

Comment: `|` translates to a newline in rst. If I remove the `|`, the two lines will appear as one. See row 1.

Comment: Which theme are you using? The alabaster theme doesn't seem to have this problem. Maybe you need some CSS rule that styles `div.line-block` and/or `div.line` differently within `table.docutils` without the leading space.

Comment: The theme is sphinx_rtd_theme. Editing the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line blocks have a left margin value in the *sphinx_rtd_theme*.  One way to get rid of them is to create a custom CSS file which imports the theme's style rules and add a rule for line blocks within tables without that margin.  Assuming the standard file and path names of a Sphinx project:

Create a `_static/css/mystyle.css` file in your Sphinx project with the following content:

```css
@import "theme.css";

table.docutils div.line-block {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Add the following option to the `conf.py`:

```
html_style = 'css/mystyle.css'
```

Rebuild the Sphinx project.